# Windows Azure Free Account

Tags: windows, web-services, azure, account

I've just created a MS Windows Azure account (with my Live ID, phone number and credit card no). The account details say that I have 30 days of free account and 150€.
I am wondering how these numbers works. I supose that I have 30 days of free account but, what about these 150€? Can I spend this money after the free account period expires? or I have to spend it within the 30 days.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While it's interesting I'm not convinced this is a good question for SO - would it suit WebMasters better?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows Azure hosting pricing.

Comment: This kind of question would be on topic for the [Virtualization, Cloud, and Grid Computing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82313/virtualization-cloud-and-grid-computing?referrer=1h2gD6-qXfE2Srvu_ObuTg2) proposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a credit up to 150€ ($200 USD) for the first month. After the 30-day trial it expires.

Answer (score 2):

You can spend this amount within 30 days. 
The free account ends when you reach the $ 150 or 30 days.